# Command line parameter parsing

Tags: c#, command-line

I'm trying to create some kind of auto login for my application via the command line. For this I've thought of the following way:

`myapp.exe /autologin -u "Username" -p "Password"`

Now first of all: Is this the correct approach (in terms of naming and switches?) and second: how can I make the parsing of this?

I've  tried it like that, but failed (or at least I think I failed because I have to manually do string operations):

```
    internal static void SetStartupArguments(List<string> arguments)
    {
        IsApplicationWarmup = arguments.Contains("/warmup");
        IsApplicationAutoLogin = arguments.Contains("/autologin");

        if (IsApplicationAutoLogin)
        {
            int autoLoginIndex = arguments.FindIndex(0, str => str == "/autologin");

            if (arguments.Count >= autoLoginIndex + 1)
            {
                AutoLoginUser = arguments[autoLoginIndex + 1];
                AutoLoginPassword = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

The other thing is, that this is quite error prone. I can't tell if the -u or the -p switch comes first, so my fear is that I end up using the password as the username and vice-versa.

Comment: I'd just iterate over the arguments and when you encounter `-u` the next argument is the user; when you encounter `-p` the next argument is the password.

Comment: You could force validation logic using Regex. Is this application a console application or a winforms app? With console, the entry point to main has built in parameter/argument handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a 3rd party library for command-line argument parsing - it can make your life much simpler.

For example, in [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) we use ["Command Line Parser Library"](https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline), which we actually embed into the source rather than adding it as an assembly reference. It's very simple to use - you just provide a class with attributes to say which command line option corresponds to which property. You could look at the [options for our TZDB compiler](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime.TzdbCompiler/CompilerOptions.cs) as an example.

Your needs may vary of course, but it's likely that there's a library which will satisfy them - and if there isn't, that suggests that perhaps your requirements are actually too complicated for a useful command line, and you may want some other way of configuring your application, e.g. via a file which is itself specified on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole its an extension of NDesk.Options and really easy to use for parsing command lines.

Example:

```
   string data = null;
   bool help   = false;
   int verbose = 0;
   var p = new OptionSet () {
    { "file=",      v => data = v },
    { "v|verbose",  v => { ++verbose } },
    { "h|?|help",   v => help = v != null },
   };
   List<string> extra = p.Parse (args);
```